# Weird behavior with css transitions inside a loop

Tags: javascript, async-await, css-transitions

I've noticed some strange behavior and don't know what to make of it. For simplicity's sake, lets say I have a div that I want to move to  the right and then back again, over and over in a loop. So I made the following transition:

```
.moving-right{
    transition: transform 0.5s;
    transform: translateX(50px);
}
```

And I set up my javascript like this:

```
async function move () {
    while (true){
        document.querySelector('.box').classList.add('moving-right')
        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 400));
        document.querySelector('.box').classList.remove('moving-right')
    }
}

move()
```

The transition only happens onscreen once. I can fix that by awaiting a very small timeout between function calls:

```
async function move () {
    while (true){
        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1)); // This Fixes it!
        document.querySelector('.box').classList.add('moving-right')
        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 400));
        document.querySelector('.box').classList.remove('moving-right')
    }
}

move()
```

Now the transition happens over and over. Why does that one line fix it? At first I thought maybe it was because removing the transition and readding it was happening too fast, so I tried adding a computation in between:

```
async function move () {
    while (true){
        for (i=0; i<1000; i++){
            if (i % 100 === 0){
                console.log(i)
            }
        }
        document.querySelector('.box').classList.add('moving-right')
        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 400));
        document.querySelector('.box').classList.remove('moving-right')
    }
}

move()
```

It still only happens once. I'm very confused by this behavior. Why would awaiting a timeout of 1ms reset the transition, but a loop with a computation wouldnt? I imagine it has something to do with how the browser renders things, but I'm not sure

Comment: This has nothing to do with your question, which is written quite well by the way--bravo, but a @keyframes CSS animation would be much simpler and requires no JS :)

Comment: "*I thought maybe it was because removing the transition and readding it was happening too fast*" - you were kinda right. However, what distinguishes it that the two DOM manipulations are done during the same synchronous execution of javascript, and the browser doesn't re-render anything until the js is done. The timeout, on the other hand, is asynchronous.

Comment: @Bergi Thank you so much for the response. That is really interesting. Would you be able to point me to where I can learn more about this process? I had no idea the browser won't re-render during synchronous js and I'd like to educate myself on this kind of behavior.

Comment: let t = document.querySelector('.box').clientLeft;
would also work :-) 
search for: "js reflow repaint layout thrashing"